# Why don't match 5 data in one row that received from Android app in database

Tags: php, android, mysql, database, row

I have a problem in mysql server
i have an android app that send to server this data:
voice ,comment,title,spinner and other
and I send voice with a code and send other text data with Asynchttpclient library.
and when I received all data of 1 user I want all of data save on 1 row 
for example

```
id  title  description  category  voice             status
1   hi     hi           1         upload/voice.mp3   1
```

but when user send this data to php file
sql makes 2 row like this:

```
id  title  description  category  voice    status
1   hi     hi           1         upload/  1
```

and

```
id  title  description  category  voice             status
2   hi     hi           1         upload/voice.mp3  1
```

what is my problem?
this is my php code:

```
<?php
send();

function connectToDatabase() {
    $connection=mysqli_connect("***", "***", "***", "***");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
      echo "Error is" . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    mysqli_set_charset($connection,"utf8");
    return $connection;
}


function send() {
    $file_path = "uploads/";

    $file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path) ){
        echo "success";
    } 

    $connection = connectToDatabase();
    $Username = $_REQUEST['Username'];
    $Title = $_REQUEST['Title'];
    $Desc = $_REQUEST['Desc'];
    $City = $_REQUEST['City'];
    $Cate = $_REQUEST['Cate'];
    $file_path=$file_path;

    $Timee = date("Y/m/d G:i");

    $result = mysqli_query($connection,"insert into banners 
        (Username,Title,Descript,City,Cate,Date,voice,Status) 
        values 
        ('$Username','$Title','$Desc','$City','$Cate','$Timee','$file_path','1')"
    );

    if($result!=""){
        print "ok";
    }else {
        print "no";
    }
}

return;
?>
```

and my Activity in android for send datas to server:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.afollestad.materialdialogs.MaterialDialog;
import com.koushikdutta.async.http.AsyncHttpClient;
import com.koushikdutta.async.http.AsyncHttpPost;
import com.koushikdutta.async.http.AsyncHttpResponse;
import com.koushikdutta.async.http.body.MultipartFormDataBody;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Random;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class New_Banners extends AppCompatActivity {


    int serverResponseCode = 0;
    ProgressDialog dialog = null;

    String upLoadServerUri = null;


    //    Development by SmartMob (Manager : Mohammad Mokhles)
    EditText new_banners_title, new_banners_desc;
    Spinner new_banners_city, new_banners_cate;
    Button StartButton, StopButton;


    String[] cates = {"لوازم الکترونیکی => موبایل", "لوازم الکترونیکی => تبلت", "لوازم الکترونیکی => لپ تاپ", "املاک => خرید و فروش", "املاک => رهن و اجازه", "کاریابی => بازاریاب", "کاریابی => مهندس", "کاریابی => پزشک"};
    String[] cates_code = {"1,1", "1,2", "1,3", "2,1", "2,2", "3,1", "3,2", "3,3"};

    String patch = "";
    String city = "";
    String cate = "";
    Snackbar snackbar;


    MediaRecorder audiocapture;


    MaterialDialog wait;
    FloatingActionButton btn_send, btn_send_ch;
    MediaRecorder recorder;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.new_banners);
        ini();


        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_city = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row_spinner_two, citys);
        new_banners_city.setAdapter(adapter_city);
        new_banners_city.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                city = citys_code[position];
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                city = citys_code[0];
            }
        });

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_cate = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row_spinner_two, cates);
        new_banners_cate.setAdapter(adapter_cate);
        new_banners_cate.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                cate = cates_code[position];
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                cate = cates_code[0];
            }
        });

        recorder = new MediaRecorder();
        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        tempFilename = System.currentTimeMillis()+".mp3";
        recorder.setOutputFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +"/"+tempFilename);
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

        StopButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.StartButton)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                try {
                    recorder.prepare();
                    recorder.start();
                    StartButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    StopButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                            .make(new_banners_title, " " +
                                    "D:", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);

                    snackbar.show();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        });


        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.StopButton)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                try {
                    recorder.stop();
                    StopButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                            .make(new_banners_title, " " +
                                    "عه:))", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);

                    snackbar.show();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        });

        btn_send.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        btn_send_ch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(New_Banners.this, webview.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                btn_send.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                btn_send_ch.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }
        });


        btn_send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                if (new_banners_title.getText().toString().equals("") || new_banners_title.length() < 10) {
                    Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                            .make(new_banners_title, " " +
                                    "10 و", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);

                    snackbar.show();


                } else if (new_banners_desc.getText().toString().equals("") || new_banners_desc.length() < 30) {
                    Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                            .make(new_banners_title, " " +
                                    " حداقل D:", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);

                    snackbar.show();
                } else {


                    wait.show();
                    send(new_banners_title.getText().toString(), new_banners_desc.getText().toString(), city, cate);

                }

            }
        });

    }


    private void send(String Title, String Desc, String City, String Cate) {

        AsyncHttpPost post = new AsyncHttpPost(
                "http://myserver.zili.ir/new_banners.php"
        );

        post.setTimeout(5000);

        MultipartFormDataBody body = new MultipartFormDataBody();

        body.addStringPart("Username", MainActivity.sp.getString("Username", null));
        body.addStringPart("Title", Title);
        body.addStringPart("Desc", Desc);
        body.addStringPart("City", City);
        body.addStringPart("Cate", Cate);

        post.setBody(body);

        AsyncHttpClient.getDefaultInstance().executeString(post, new AsyncHttpClient.StringCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(final Exception e, AsyncHttpResponse source, String result) {

                if (e != null) {

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            wait.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(New_Banners.this, "خطا در برقراری اتصال با سرور !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    });

                }

                if (result.equals("ok")) {

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            wait.dismiss();
                      //      Toast.makeText(New_Banners.this, "tnx", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            finish();
                        }
                    });

                } else if (result.equals("no")) {

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            wait.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(New_Banners.this, "خطا در ثبت آگهی", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });

                } else if (result.equals("error")) {

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            wait.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(New_Banners.this, "خطا در ثبت !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });

                }

            }
        });

        dialog.show();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

             uploadFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+File.separator+tempFilename) ;
            }
        }).start();


    }


    String TAG = "tag";
String tempFilename = "";
    public int uploadFile(final String selectedFilePath) {

        int serverResponseCode = 0;

        HttpURLConnection connection;
        DataOutputStream dataOutputStream;
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";


        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
        File selectedFile = new File(selectedFilePath);


        String[] parts = selectedFilePath.split("/");
        final String fileName = parts[parts.length - 1];

        if (!selectedFile.isFile()) {
            dialog.dismiss();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(New_Banners.this, "file notfound", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //tvFileName.setText("Source File Doesn't Exist: " + selectedFilePath);
                }
            });
            return 0;
        } else {
            try {
                FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(selectedFile);
                URL url = new URL("http://myserver.zili.ir/new_banners.php");
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setDoInput(true);//Allow Inputs
                connection.setDoOutput(true);//Allow Outputs
                connection.setUseCaches(false);//Don't use a cached Copy
                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                connection.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                connection.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", selectedFilePath);

                //creating new dataoutputstream
                dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());

                //writing bytes to data outputstream
                dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                        + selectedFilePath + "\"" + lineEnd);

                dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                //returns no. of bytes present in fileInputStream
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                //selecting the buffer size as minimum of available bytes or 1 MB
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                //setting the buffer as byte array of size of bufferSize
                buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                //reads bytes from FileInputStream(from 0th index of buffer to buffersize)
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                //loop repeats till bytesRead = -1, i.e., no bytes are left to read
                while (bytesRead > 0) {
                    //write the bytes read from inputstream
                    dataOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                }

                dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
                String serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();

                Log.i(TAG, "Server Response is: " + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

                //response code of 200 indicates the server status OK
                if (serverResponseCode == 200) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(New_Banners.this, "file uplaod successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            //   tvFileName.setText("File Upload completed.\n\n You can see the uploaded file here: \n\n" + "http://coderefer.com/extras/uploads/"+ fileName);
                        }
                    });
                }

                //closing the input and output streams
                fileInputStream.close();
                dataOutputStream.flush();
                dataOutputStream.close();


            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(New_Banners.this, "File Not Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(New_Banners.this, "URL error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(New_Banners.this, "Cannot Read/Write File!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            dialog.dismiss();
            return serverResponseCode;
        }

    }


    private void ini() {

        wait = new MaterialDialog.Builder(New_Banners.this)
                .content("لطفا صبر کنید ...")
                .progress(true, 0)
                .cancelable(false)
                .build();

        btn_send = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_send);
        new_banners_title = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.new_banners_title);
        new_banners_desc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.new_banners_desc);
        StartButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.StartButton);
        StopButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.StopButton);
        new_banners_city = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.new_banners_city);
        new_banners_cate = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.new_banners_cate);
        btn_send_ch = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_send_ch);
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        dialog.setMessage("صبر کن...");

    }


}
```

and my row when send data
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7DyD.jpg)

Comment: You are _wide open_ to SQL Injections and should use parameterized [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead.

Comment: Never post code with your real db credentials (or any other kind of credentials).

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i changed my database user and pw:D

Comment: I'm no Java expert (or not even a novice), but it looks like you're making two calls? One with the data (the send() method) and then another for the file (the uploadFile() method)? You need to send them in the same request.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson yes this is true but i cant send both of them with 1 request , there is no way for this problem?:|

Comment: Why can't you send them in the same request? That's a pretty standard way of doing it. If you, for some undeclared reason can't, then you need to send the data first, return the ID and then when you post the file, you pass the ID with it and do an update instead of insert on the last created record (by it's id). Or do it the other way around, send the file first, insert it, return the ID and do an update with the data on that ID.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson can u write that u say in my code please im new in dev<3

Comment: No I can't. As I stated, I'm not a Java developer. Also, SO isn't a "write-that-for-me"-site. I've given you the reason you get double rows in your DB and given you examples of how to fix it. Now it's up to you to do the proper research and learn how to actually implement it. If you then get stuck on something specific while trying, come back show us what you've tried an I'm sure someone will be able to help you.